# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected output to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (2,)

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to create my face detection model on google colab tpu. 
Basically, it's a copy of VGG16. Has same layers except the first one and the last three.
It runs on Python 2 notebook on colab.

I've seen other questions, they all get more than required members in an array and there are solutions for them. 
Others are unanswered.

It raises an error when run the cell with training code for my model.

```python
#img_data contains images converted to array and pre-processed 
img_data = np.array(img_data_list)
img_data=np.rollaxis(img_data,1,0)
img_data =img_data[0]

#outputs
(2000, 1, 224, 224, 3)
(1, 2000, 224, 224, 3)
(1, 2000, 224, 224, 3)

num_classes = 2
num_of_samples = img_data.shape[0]
labels = np.ones((num_of_samples,),dtype='int64')
labels[0:1000]=0
labels[1000:]=1
names = ['happy' , 'not happy']

Y = np_utils.to_categorical(labels, num_classes)

x,y = shuffle(img_data,Y, random_state=2)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=2)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(input_shape=(224,224,3)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (5, 5), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (5, 5), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D())

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (5, 5), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (5, 5), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2)))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (5, 5), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (5, 5), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (5, 5), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2)))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (5, 5), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (5, 5), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (5, 5), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2)))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (5, 5), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (5, 5), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(512, (5, 5), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2)))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', name='fc1'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu', name='fc2'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='output'))
model.summary()
```

## Training the model

```python
import os
tpu_model = tf.contrib.tpu.keras_to_tpu_model(
    model,
    strategy=tf.contrib.tpu.TPUDistributionStrategy(
        tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'])
    )
)
tpu_model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-3, ),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,
    metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy']
)

def train_gen(batch_size):
  while True:
    offset = np.random.randint(0, x_train.shape[0] - batch_size)
    yield x_train[offset:offset+batch_size], y_train[offset:offset + batch_size]


tpu_model.fit_generator(
    train_gen(1024),
    epochs=10,
    steps_per_epoch=100,
    verbose = 1,
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
)
```

## Expected results :

Array with probabilities of each label.

## Actual results :

```python
ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-bffa1e87ffe0> in <module>()
     24     steps_per_epoch=100,
     25     verbose = 1,
---> 26     validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
     27 )
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected output to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (2,)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I was using the wrong loss function and metrics.
After setting

```
loss = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy']
```

I finally get it running.

Answer (score 0):

your problem maybe is that y label should be processed `onehot`, 
you used `tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy` could ignore this procedure.